# Logging in Console app, example from docs not working

Tags: c#, logging, console

I am trying to wrap my head around logging in C# .NET console app and have issues running [this example from the Microsoft docs] using /NET 4.8 and Visual Studio 2017. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#non-host-console-app):

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
                .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
                .AddFilter("LoggingConsoleApp.Program", LogLevel.Debug)
                .AddConsole();
        });

        ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
        logger.LogInformation("Example log message");
    }
}
```

Intellisense complains about the var keyword not being expected and a parenthesis is required, as expressed in this build output as well:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: LoggingConsoleApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\*****\Code\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs(9,19,9,22): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected
1>C:\Users\*****\Code\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs(16,15,16,16): error CS1026: ) expected
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Already tried and wrapped the statement in parenthesis like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace LoggingConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
                    .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
                    .AddFilter("LoggingConsoleApp.Program", LogLevel.Debug)
                    .AddConsole();
            }));

            ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
            logger.LogInformation("Example log message");
        }
    }
}
```

But then build still fails like this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: LoggingConsoleApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\jonathan.martens\Code\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs(16,16,16,17): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty
1> statement
1>C:\Users\jonathan.martens\Code\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs(18,30,18,43): error CS0103: The name 'loggerFactory' 
1>does not exist in the current context
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Am I doing something wrong, am I missing something or is the example not correct?

Comment: What type of project (.NET Framework or .NET Core)?  What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: This logging interface was introduced with .NET Core. I'm not sure if it has been back-ported to .NET Framework, but if not you have other options, my favorite being Serilog.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, Net Core logging wont work in Net Framework projects. That aside, your code is incorrect anyway. You have a `USING` declared with a `loggerFactory`, and then you're calling it outside of the `using`. That wont work because its already disposed at that point.